# Laravel: Getting count of belongsToMany relation with where clause

Tags: laravel, where-clause

I'm trying to list the amount of games players played (and finished) in a data-table. Currently I use WithCount, but it turns out to be quite slow.

```php
$data = Player::withCount(['games' => function (Builder $query) {
                $query->where('ended', 1);
            }])->get();
```

Is there a better way to grab the count of records with a where condition that isn't as resource intensive?

Comment: I am pretty sure your problem is the `get()` method (PHP) and not the query, sl change `get()` to `count()` and see if it works. You can also use `toSql()` and manually run the query so you can see how long it takes and debug more.

Comment: @matiaslauriti i do also want to get the all playerdata, but only just include the count of games that ended.

Comment: And do you know the amount of models you are getting back ? It is not recommended to get more than 500k at max, can you explain more ?